# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c\in \mathbb{R}$ , show that $f'(c)$= $ \lim_{n\to\infty}$ $n${${f(c+1/n)-f(c)}$}. Is the converse true?

I've proved the first part with the help of differentiability at $c$. I think the converse is not true  but don't have any counter example. Please help...

Comment: To be pedantic, the converse of the conditional you wrote, *as literally stated*, **is** true because the conclusion of the conditional *assumes* $f'(c)$ exists. (The converse thus says "if $f'(c)=\lim\cdots$, then $f$ is differentiable at $c$." This is trivially true, because the antecedent assumes $f'(c)$ exists.) What you really mean to ask is whether the following statement is true: if the limit you give simply *exists*, then $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic counterexample would be $\sin(1/x)$ and $c=0$. You do have to tweak the function a bit to make it work in your specific case (make sure $f(1/n)=0$ for all $n$).

A simpler (but in my opinion more boring) counterexample is $|x|$, still at $c=0$.

Comment: I was thinking for $|x|$.

Comment: @SULTAN If you already have a function, what's the problem? In that case we have $f(0+1/n)-f(0)=1/n$. So you get your limit (which is $1$), but the function isn't differentiable.

Comment: @Arthur limit for |x| at 0 is 1?

Comment: @gimusi That's not the limit in the question. The limit in the question becomes $1$ if we pick $f(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Thus n is assumed to be positive? it wasn’t specified in the OP, indeed I thought that it was just a matter of derivative definition which is equivalent to differentiability in this case.

Comment: @gimusi We're taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, so it's safe to assume that $n$ is positive, which means that $\frac1n$ approaches $0$ from above. That is why you get the correct answer for a function which is right differentiable, like $|x|$, where the right derivative at $0$ is $1$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the clarification, indded I think that the OP wasn't sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate what you mean with n, if it is to be intended as **a positive number** the circumstance that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}
n(f(c+1/n)-f(c))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(c+1/n)-f(c)}{\frac1n}=\lim_{h\to0^+}
\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$ exists obviously does not guarantee that $f$ is differentiable since the limit for $h\to 0^-$ could not exist or be different.

Otherwise since the limit is the definition of derivative and since for a function in one variable **derivability $\iff$ differentiability**, if the limit exists you don’t have to prove anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely redefine $f$ at all points of the form $c+r$ where $r$ is irrational and not change the limit. This destroys the continuity at $c$.